# How to manage the treasury?

Tags: pallet-treasury

Treasury is a pot of funds to accumulate  funds to be spent for some purpose later on.

One way to manage the treasury is by a majority vote from a council like on  Kusama network. Are there other ways to manage the treasury?  If yes, what are these ways please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally up to you.

You can manage it through your custom pallet.

For example, you have a `pallet-fun`. And this pallet can transfer some balances from the treasury to a random account every block.

For Polkadot: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-treasury

Comment: If your chain doesn't already have that pallet-fun pallet then someone could submit an on-chain runtime upgrade proposal to the community who could vote in favour of it